# object moving on own in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, alerts

Sorry the code is so long. When the hero image is at most 32 pixels away from the mine or monster image, it should be transported back to the spawn point, which is 5 pixels on the x-axis, and 5 on the y axis. The hero image is being transported correctly, the alert is just not working. Thanks in advance for any ideas or suggestions.

```
<html>
<style>
</style>
<body background="background.jpg">
<canvas id="canvas" width="1300" height="630"></canvas>
<script>
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var H=canvas.height;
var W=canvas.width;
var x=10;
var y=15;
var rightPressed=false;
var leftPressed=false;
var upPressed=false; 
var downPressed=false;
var heroX=20;
var monsterX=200;  
var monsterY=200;
var heroY=20;
var dx= .68;
var dy= .76;
var score=0;
var monstersCaught=0;
var ballPX = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 64));
var ballPY = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.height - 64));
var h=178;
var i=333;
var mineX=778;
var mineY=178;

Window.onload=dank();
function dank(){
alert("How to play: move your hero using the arrow keys, and collect colored     balls for powerups and points!Get the highest score you can without touching a     monster, which makes you start over!Collect the colored balls for more and         better special powerups.");
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

function draw(){
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
var heroImage=new Image();
heroImage.onload=function(){
ctx.drawImage(heroImage , heroX, heroY);
}
heroImage.src="hero.jpg";
dope();
checkMonster();
drawMines();
checkDeath();
}
function keyDownHandler(e) {
if(e.keyCode == 39) {
rightPressed = true;
}
else if(e.keyCode == 37) {
leftPressed = true;
}
else if(e.keyCode == 40) {
downPressed = true; 
}
else if(e.keyCode == 38) {
upPressed = true;
}
}
function keyUpHandler(e) {
if(e.keyCode == 39) {
rightPressed = false;
}
else if(e.keyCode == 37) {
leftPressed = false;
} 
else if(e.keyCode == 40) {
downPressed = false;
}  
else if(e.keyCode == 38) {
upPressed = false;
}
}
function dope(){
if(rightPressed) {
heroX += 7;
}
else if(leftPressed) {
heroX -= 7;
}
else if(upPressed){
heroY -= 7;
}
else if(downPressed){
heroY +=7;
}
}
function checkMonster(){
var monsterImage=new Image();
monsterImage.onload=function(){
ctx.drawImage(monsterImage, monsterX, monsterY)
}
monsterImage.src="monster.jpg";
monsterX += dx;
monsterY += dy;
if(monsterX>canvas.width || monsterX<0){
monsterX = -dx;
}
else if(monsterY>canvas.height || monsterY<0){
monsterY = -dy;
}
if (
heroX <= (monsterX + 32)
&& monsterX <= (heroX + 32)
&& heroY <= (monsterY + 32)
&& monsterY <= (heroY + 32)
) {
```

the alert that isn't working

```
alert("DEATH");
heroY=5;
heroX=5;
monsterX=100;
monsterY=100;
upPressed=false;
downPressed=false;
leftPressed=false;
rightPressed=false;


}
}
function drawMines(){
var rsz_mineImage=new Image();
rsz_mineImage.onload=function(){
ctx.drawImage(rsz_mineImage , mineX, mineY);
}
rsz_mineImage.src="rsz_mineimg.jpg";
if (
heroX <= (mineX + 32)
&& mineX <= (heroX + 32)
&& heroY <= (mineY + 32)
&& mineY <= (heroY + 32)
){
rightPressed=false;
leftPressed=false;
upPressed=false;
downPressed=false;
heroX=5;
heroY=5;
```

one of the alerts not working

```
alert("DEATH");

}
}





setInterval(draw, 10);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the code _without_ cutting it up with your explanations? And maybe try indenting everything a bit to see clearer? Try pasting the JS in there: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me.  You had images loading in the animation loop which created a flickering effect. It's best to load your assets onto a canvas and when the images load place them on their canvas.  This way you don't have to check if the image is loaded and can have a background color as a stand-in.  Also running the animation in an interval loop isn't as efficient as using requestAnimationFrame. Also use `preventDefault` on the key input to prevent scrolling.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var H = canvas.height;
var W = canvas.width;
var x = 10;
var y = 15;
var rightPressed = false;
var leftPressed = false;
var upPressed = false;
var downPressed = false;
var heroX = 20;
var monsterX = 200;
var monsterY = 200;
var heroY = 20;
var dx = .68;
var dy = .76;
var score = 0;
var monstersCaught = 0;
var ballPX = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 64));
var ballPY = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.height - 64));
var h = 178;
var i = 333;
var mineX = 778;
var mineY = 178;

Window.onload = dank();

function dank() {
  alert("How to play: move your hero using the arrow keys, and collect colored     balls for powerups and points!Get the highest score you can without touching a     monster, which makes you start over!Collect the colored balls for more and         better special powerups.");
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

function loadImage(w,h,color,url) {
  var can = document.createElement('canvas');
  can.width = w;
  can.height = h;
  var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle=color;
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,w,h);
  var img = document.createElement('image');
  img.onLoad = function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  };
  img.src=url;
  return can;
}

// load assets
var heroImage = loadImage(32,32,'#FF9900',"hero.jpg");
var monsterImage = loadImage(32,32,'purple',"monster.jpg");
var rsz_mineImage = loadImage(32,32,'#FF3300',"rsz_mineimg.jpg");

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(heroImage, heroX, heroY);
  dope();
  checkMonster();
  drawMines();
  //checkDeath();
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function keyDownHandler(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = true;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    leftPressed = true;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    downPressed = true;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    upPressed = true;
  }
  e.preventDefault();
}

function keyUpHandler(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = false;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    leftPressed = false;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    downPressed = false;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    upPressed = false;
  }
  e.preventDefault();
}

function dope() {
  if (rightPressed) {
    heroX += 7;
  } else if (leftPressed) {
    heroX -= 7;
  } else if (upPressed) {
    heroY -= 7;
  } else if (downPressed) {
    heroY += 7;
  }
}

function checkMonster() {
  
  ctx.drawImage(monsterImage, monsterX, monsterY)
  monsterX += dx;
  monsterY += dy;
  if (monsterX > canvas.width || monsterX < 0) {
    monsterX = -dx;
  } else if (monsterY > canvas.height || monsterY < 0) {
    monsterY = -dy;
  }
  if (
    heroX <= (monsterX + 32) && monsterX <= (heroX + 32) && heroY <= (monsterY + 32) && monsterY <= (heroY + 32)
  ) {
    alert("DEATH");
    heroY = 5;
    heroX = 5;
    monsterX = 100;
    monsterY = 100;
    upPressed = false;
    downPressed = false;
    leftPressed = false;
    rightPressed = false;


  }
}

function drawMines() {

  ctx.drawImage(rsz_mineImage, mineX, mineY);
  
  if (
    heroX <= (mineX + 32) && mineX <= (heroX + 32) && heroY <= (mineY + 32) && mineY <= (heroY + 32)
  ) {
    rightPressed = false;
    leftPressed = false;
    upPressed = false;
    downPressed = false;
    heroX = 5;
    heroY = 5;
    alert("DEATH");

  }
}

draw();
```

```css
#canvas {
  width:100%;
  background-color:#eff0de;
}
body {
  background-color:#AADDFF;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="1300" height="630"></canvas>
```